# ¿Cómo usar dos o más modelos para listar en un template?, django

Tags: django

Necesito listar múltiples registros de múltiples modelos no relacionados entre si en una sola plantilla. Alguien puede ayudarme?
Básicamente es una agenda con envió de mensajes, pero toda la vista se realiza en 1 solo template y necesito visualizar 2 listas:
1ra lista de contactos
2da lista de mensajes enviados.
Las tablas no tienen una relación directa por lo que no puedo traerla por su foreign key, la base de datos no se puede modificar.
Aquí dejo parte de código del template y la vista.

*--Consulta de primera tabla*

```
{% for grupos in object_list %}
  <div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h5 class="panel-title">
      <a role="tab" id="headingOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">
        {{ grupos.nombre }}</a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
    <a role="button"><i class="fa fa-plus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Agregar a la bandeja de enviados"></i></a></i>
    <a href="" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Editar"></i></a>
    <a href="" role="button"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar"></i></a>
  </ul></h5>
</div>
<div id="collapse" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
<div class="panel-body">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item"><small>escribimos algo largo para ver el limite de la cadena</small>
      <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
        <a role="button"><i class="fa fa-plus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Agregar a la bandeja de enviados"></i></a></i>
        <a href="" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Editar"></i></a>
        <a href="" role="button"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar"></i></a>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

{% endfor %}

*--Consulta de segunda tabla*

```
{% for mensaje in object_list %}
 <div class="sender-info">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <strong class="date"> {{ mensaje.hora_enviado}} / {{ mensaje.fecha_enviado }} </strong>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
 <div class="view-mail">
<p><h5>{{ mensaje.contenido }}</h5></p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

*Vista*

```
from apps.agenda.models import Mensaje, Grupos

class index(ListView):
  model = Mensaje
  second_model = Grupos
  template_name = 'agenda/index.html'
  paginate_by = 40
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay varias maneras de hacer esto:

Usando un listView y añadiendo el objeto que necesitas en el contexto, podrías usar estos objetos en el template. Pero te va a ser difícil generar eventos dependiendo del usuario

```
class index(ListView):
  model = Mensaje
  second_model = Grupos
  template_name = 'agenda/index.html'
  paginate_by = 40

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(customerUpdateView,elf).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['obj1'] = TuModelo.objects.all()
        context['obj2'] = TuOtroModelo.objects.filter(tipo='eventos')
        return context
```

Personalmente cuando hay envueltos varios modelos y condicionales dependiendo de por ejemplo: el usuario, prefiero crearme las vistas a mano.

```
def tu_ejemplo_de_vista(request):

   objeto1 = Calendatio.objects.filter(tipo='evento')
   objeto2 = Eventos.objects.filter(usuario=request.user)

   return render(request, "tu/path/calendario.html", {'eventos':objeto1, 'eventos_usuario':objeto2})
```

(*La url seria igual sin el .as_view())

En este segundo ejemplo podrás recorrer de la misma manera los elementos en la template, pero no se llamarán  object_list si no eventos y eventos_usuario

Comment: Me sirvió tu ejemplo, pero me encontré con otro, problema.
cada grupo tiene n empleados, conectados por su forgein, como puedo mostrar los empleados de cada grupo?

Comment: Pues dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer y depende de la cantidad de datos que suponga eso. Podrías solo pasar los grupos y en el onclick del grupo llamar a un ajax que te devuelva los empleados, o procesarlo en back como un diccionario y construirlo en el template.
De todos modos te recomiendo cerrar esta pregunta si es que está resuelta y abrir otra nueva con ejemplos, por que en comentarios es difícil de poner código.

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas sencilla de hacer esto es con un *TemplateView* de esta forma:

views.py

```
class index(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'agenda/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        mensajes = Mensaje.objects.all()
        grupos = Grupos.objects.all()
        return {'mensajes': mensajes, 'grupos': grupos}
```

Y para que lo veas en el template seria de esta forma.

template.html

```
{% for mensaje in mensajes %}
    <div>
        {{mensaje.contenido}}
    </div>
{% endfor %}

{% for grupo in grupos %}
    {{grupos.nombre}}
{% endfor %}
```